javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException:RESTEASY003215: could not find writer for content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded type: javax.ws.rs.core.Form$1
ERROR IsvProvisioningManager error occour in createRealmRESTEASY004655: Unable to invoke request: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY003215: could not find writer for content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded type: javax.ws.rs.core.Form$1
Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY004655: Unable to invoke request: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY003215: could not find writer for content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded type: javax.ws.rs.core.Form$1
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:341)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:464)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invokeSync(ClientInvoker.java:152)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invoke(ClientInvoker.java:115)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:76)
at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy32.grantToken(Unknown Source)
at org.keycloak.admin.client.token.TokenManager.grantToken(TokenManager.java:98)
at org.keycloak.admin.client.token.TokenManager.getAccessToken(TokenManager.java:74)
at org.keycloak.admin.client.token.TokenManager.getAccessTokenString(TokenManager.java:69)
at org.keycloak.admin.client.resource.BearerAuthFilter.filter(BearerAuthFilter.java:52)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.filterRequest(ClientInvocation.java:660)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:461)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invokeSync(ClientInvoker.java:152)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invoke(ClientInvoker.java:115)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:76)
at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy41.create(Unknown Source)
at com.sfnt.ems.service.keycloak.provisioning.IsvProvisioningManager.createRole(IsvProvisioningManager.java:596)
at com.sfnt.ems.service.keycloak.provisioning.IsvProvisioningManager.createRoles(IsvProvisioningManager.java:527)
at com.sfnt.ems.service.keycloak.provisioning.IsvProvisioningManager.createRealm(IsvProvisioningManager.java:70)
Tried to execute jar which contain dependencies :
  dependencies {


implementation('org.keycloak:keycloak-admin-client:18.0.0'){
  exclude group: 'org.jboss.resteasy', module: 'resteasy-client'
}
implementation group: 'com.sun.xml.fastinfoset', name: 'FastInfoset', version: '1.2.15'
implementation group: 'com.sun.mail', name: 'imap', version: '1.6.2'
implementation group: 'org.keycloak', name: 'keycloak-events-api', version: '1.8.1.Final'
implementation group: 'org.keycloak', name: 'keycloak-model-api', version: '1.8.1.Final'
compileOnly('org.keycloak:keycloak-services:18.0.0'){
  exclude group: 'org.keycloak', module: 'keycloak-core'
  exclude group: 'org.keycloak', module: 'keycloak-common'
  exclude group: 'org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs', module: 'jboss-jaxrs-api_2.1_spec'
  exclude group: 'org.jboss.logging', module: 'jboss-logging'
  exclude group:'com.openshift', module: 'openshift-restclient-java'
  exclude group:'org.yaml', module:'snakeyaml'
}
 implementation ('com.sntl:sm-cloud-env-client:2.0.2'){
        exclude group: 'commons-httpclient', module: 'commons-httpclient'
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
        //exclude group: 'org.springframework.vault', module: 'spring-vault-core'
    }
//implementation group: 'org.springframework.vault', name: 'spring-vault-core', version: '2.3.2'
implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.12.0'


// Use JUnit Jupiter for testing.
testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.8.1'



// This dependency is used internally, and not exposed to consumers on their own compile classpath.
implementation group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '31.1-jre'

}

Looks like you didn't add the dependancy. Did you verified your JAR file? Check if these items are added in the build

Added Keycloak-admin-client and services jar under dependency.

In my experience, my keycloak app version was 19.0.2,  keycloak-admin-client dependency version was 19.0.2, and I was facing this error. I am using jdk-17 by the way. I upgrade my keycloak-admin-client dependency to 22.0.5 and it works, I did not experience any problems. Probably, there were no changes in the keycloak rest APIs between 19.02 and 22.0.5. However, it is useful to check the migration guides before trying this method.
